# how to check missing files from directory via php

Tags: php

I use the code below to list all files in directory and its working great.

```
function ck($path){
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        $files = glob($path ."/*");

//check if file exist in that directory
    if(count($files) > 0){
            // Loop through retuned array
            foreach($files as $file){
                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    echo "$file"  . "<br>";
                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    // Recursively call the function if directories found
                    ck("$file");
                }
            }

        }

else{
            echo "ERROR: No such file found in the directory.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}

// Call the function
ck("C:/xampp/htdocs/test");
```

Now am trying to check for deleted files from the directory by comparing the filename in the directory with filename in the database.

In my directory **C:/xampp/htdocs/test**
i have five files

```
1.php, 2.php, 3.php, 4.php, 5.php
```

so in my database i have the above listed 5 filenames stored. Now I went to directory and and manually 
deleted two file(eg. **2.php and 4.php**) without deleting its filename from the database.

How do I use my database to compare and get the missig filename in the directory.

The code below only compare database and show all the files in the directory but does not tell me that file **2.php and 4.php** is missing.

Please how do I get the missing files name

```
function ck($path){
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        $files = glob($path ."/*");

//check if file exist in that directory
    if(count($files) > 0){
            // Loop through retuned array
            foreach($files as $file){
                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    //echo "$file"  . "<br>";

//db connection
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tab_file where dataf = :dataf ");
        $result->execute(array(
':dataf' => $file
    ));

$count = $result->rowCount();
if( $count > 0 ) {

echo "files found: $file";
}else{

//echo missing files
echo "This $file has been deletd</b></font><br><br>"; 

}

                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    // Recursively call the function if directories found
                    ck("$file");
                }
            }

        }

else{
            echo "ERROR: No such file found in the directory.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}

// Call the function
ck("C:/xampp/htdocs/test");
```

Comment: What is the question here you already return missing file ?

Comment: it's not showing me the missing files(2.php and 4.php) . it only shows me (file 1.php, 3.php,5.php). 2.php and 4.php has been deleted from directory but their filename is still in the database

Comment: You should not perform database queries inside loops, that is usually bad in terms of performance. Read all your records from the database, loop over those - and inside the loop, simply check if the file from the current record exists on the HDD …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need change algorithm logic you search for each file in directory you have to check for each file in MySQL also don't use MySQL in loop

```
<?php
    function ck($path){
        if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
            $result = $db->get_col("SELECT filename FROM tab_file ORDER BY id ASC");
            $count = $result->rowCount();
            if($count > 0) {
                foreach ($results as $filename) {
                    $file = file_exists($path ."/*".$filename);
                    if(iseet($file) > 0){
                        echo "SUCCESS: File : $filename exist";
                    }else{
                        echo "ERROR: The File : $filename does not exist or deleted.";
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
        }
    }

    // Call the function
    ck("C:/xampp/htdocs/test");
```